# How could one extract visible and near-infrared images data separately from Raspberry Pi Noir V2 camera?

Tags: python, image-processing, camera, raspberry-pi, infrared

I am trying to extract Visible and Near-infrared images data separately from a single Image taken using Raspberry Pi Noir V2 camera without blue filter. I'm using Raw data format for the conversion.